# Can't release ViewController in function

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Why can't I use `[y release]` at the end of function?

```
- (void)functionused:(NSTimer *)timer
{   
    [password resignFirstResponder]; 
    mainViewController* y=[[mainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"mainViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *currentView = (UIView *)[timer userInfo];

    for ( UIView *subview in [self.view.superview subviews] ) {

        if ((subview.tag != 14)) {

            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    [currentView.superview addSubview:[y view]];

    //[y release];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that will bring the reference count of mainViewController to zero and it will be deallocated. You need to keep a reference to it around somewhere.

The line `[currentView.superview addSubview:[y view]];` only adds it's view to the superview. The view will be retained, but the controller itself won't.

Comment: but i have potentiel leak in this function haw i can do?

Comment: sorry but what mean keep reference?

Comment: First of all, dtuckernet points out a very valid point. It's crucial that you understand the difference between views and view controllers. With keep a reference I mean that you probably want an instance variable to put the mainViewController in.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need to understand the difference between a UIView and a UIViewController.  The UIViewController contains a pointer to the UIView instance, but the UIView does not contain a direct reference to the UIViewController.  So - when you add the view controller's view to the currentView's superview, it's retain count increments.  However, this does not increment the retain count for the view controller.  It would go to 0 if released and this would cause the view controller to be deallocated.

Comment: You can release it when you are done with it - but not before.